# How to call an argument from Java to Dart using MethodChannel?

Tags: java, flutter, dart, flutter-method-channel

I am trying to call an argument from my Java native code to Dart,
I have a method in my Java code -

```
@Override
public void onReward(final int quantity) {
    HashMap<String, Object> args = new HashMap<>();
    args.put("reward",quantity);
    Log.i("TheoremReach", "onRewardCenterOpened");
    TrsurveysPlugin.getInstance().OnMethodCallHandler("onReward", args);
}
```

I am storing my `args` in my `HashMap` and passing it as an argument using my `OnMethodCallHandler`

```
void OnMethodCallHandler(final String method, final HashMap<String,Object> args) {
    try {
        TrsurveysPlugin.activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                channel.invokeMethod(method, args);
            }
        });
     } catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e("Trsurveys", "Error " + e.toString());
     }
 }
```

How do I call this in my Dart code? Here's my current attempt -

This is how I get a callback from the Java side of code, however this doesn't return my `int quantity` from the method -

```
typedef TheoremListener(TheoremReachListener listener);

static final Map<String, TheoremReachListener> theoremReachListener = {
    'onReward': TheoremReachListener.onReward,
};

static Future<void> handleMethod(
    MethodCall call, TheoremListener listener) async {
    listener(theoremReachListener[call.method]);
}
```

Here is my listener from my example repo, it prints the `onReward` but doesn't return my argument

```
listener(TheoremReachListener event) {
    if (event == TheoremReachListener.onReward) {
        print('on reward');
    } 
}
```